# Bypass proxy when calling a web service from a Windows service

Tags: vb.net, web-services, windows-services, web-reference

I have a Windows service that is calling a web service, passing a string, and returning a success or error message.

Everything has worked fine in all my testing and development... until I tried to roll it out internally on a network with a proxy server.  The web service addresses are not internal but they need to bypass the proxy server to work correctly.  If I disconnect my machine from our network and access the internet directly it works fine and the web service is accessible, but if I am connected to the corporate network it fails.

I can add a service reference fine because that uses the proxy settings for my user and this address is set to bypass the proxy.  I have tried to run the service with my user credentials and it still doesn't work.

This is what I am using to call the web service:

```
    Dim results As String
    Dim objJob As CheckValidationKey.ImportProjectInfo = New CheckValidationKey.ImportProjectInfo
    objJob.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

    results = objJob.CheckValidationKey(ValidationKey)
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to bypass the proxy.  I have tried options in the app.config without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get an answer and would still like one, however, this specific issue is no longer a problem.  It turns out that the proxy wasn't even the problem, but rather that the specific network segment I was trying to use had soap requests blocked.  All those hours!